# How can I scale my game for different resolutions while using MVC

Tags: java, resolution, scaling

I want to be able to scale my game for different resolutions, but I'm only allowed to work in the controller (I'm using MVC). I'm not sure how to make my game scale.

I haven't really tried anything yet since I'm not familiar with scaling games for different resolutions. Is there a special function for that?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import se.egy.game.resourses.Drawable;
import se.egy.game.resourses.GameCloseException;


public class GameScreen{

    private int height, width;
    private String title;
    private boolean fullScreenMode = false;

    private JFrame jf;

    private GraphicsDevice device;
    private BufferStrategy backBuffer;
    private Graphics2D g;

    private Color bgColor = Color.BLACK; // Svart, default som bakgrund
    private Image bgImg = null;

    private DisplayMode oldDM = null;

    public GameScreen(String title, int width, int height, boolean fulScreenMode) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.title = title;
        this.fullScreenMode = fulScreenMode;

        try {
            EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    createWindow();
                }
            });
        }catch(Exception e) {}

        clearScreen();

        if(fullScreenMode) { // Ful lösning ;-)
            jf.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
            try{ Thread.sleep(50);}catch(Exception e){}
        }

    }

    public GameScreen(String title, int width, int height) {
        this(title, width, height, false);
    }


    private void createWindow() {
        jf = new JFrame(title);

        if(fullScreenMode) {
            DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(width, height, 32, 0);
            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();

            jf.setUndecorated(true);
            jf.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

            oldDM = device.getDisplayMode();

            device.setFullScreenWindow(jf);
            device.setDisplayMode(dm);
        }else {
            jf.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
            jf.setResizable(false);
            jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        jf.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.requestFocus();

        jf.createBufferStrategy(2);
        backBuffer = jf.getBufferStrategy();
    }
```

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import se.egy.game.model.Entity;
import se.egy.game.model.Sprite;
import se.egy.game.view.GameScreen;
import se.egy.game.view.TxtEntity;

public class GameController implements KeyListener{
    private GameScreen gs;

    private boolean gameRunning = true;
    private int fps;

    private Entity player;

    private ArrayList<Entity> entityList = new ArrayList<>();

    private HashMap<String, Boolean> keyDown = new HashMap<>();

    public GameController(GameScreen gs, int fps) {
        this.gs = gs;
        this.gs.setKeyListener(this);

        this.fps = fps;

        resetkeyDown();

        loadObjects();
    }
        public void runGame() {
        long renderDelay = 1000000000/fps;

        long lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();

        while(gameRunning) {
            long deltaTime = System.nanoTime() - lastUpdateTime;

            if(deltaTime >= renderDelay) {
                lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
                gs.render(entityList);
                update(deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want the game to work for different resolutions. So that my "enemies", as well as the player, is on the same position for a 1920 x 1080 resolution as an 800 x 600 resolution. There is a bit more code to both the GameScreen(view) and to the GameController(controller), but I don't think it's necessary to show more. My model is only of the entities that I'm using for the game, such as the player and the enemies.

Comment: What GUI library? What do your Model, your Controller and your View code look like? Please clarify the question by telling the details and by showing pertinent code. Please go through the [ask] as well as the [How do I ask and answer Homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Comment: hopefully this edit makes it easier to help me @HovercraftFullOfEels